# How to put the GET parameter in nginx rewrite rule?

Tags: nginx, get, url-rewriting

I'm very new to nginx and just working with the rewrite rule

I want my domain http://example.com/database/view.php?id=1

to show as http://example.com/database/id/

with the GET parameter showing in the url where "id" is, is that possible?

I have attempted this :

```html
 rewrite ^/database/$arg_id? /database/view.php?id=[1-9]* last;
```

and

```
location @database {
     rewrite ^/view/(.*) /view.php?id=$1&$args last;
     }
```

and they failed resulting in example.com/database/view/51 as a 404

Comment: Did your application have single entry point? If no - you got 404, because Nginx could not find anything at given path.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it :)

Solved with

```html
rewrite ^/view/(.*)/ /database/view.php?id=$1&$args last;
```